# Why is reference path needed to compile anglularjs 2 project with gulp-typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I wanted to change the [Angular Tour Of Heros](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) project to build with gulp [Github Repo](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes).

I created the following `gulpfile.json`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

// clean the contents of the distribution directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del('dist/**/*');
});

// TypeScript compile
gulp.task('compile', ['clean'], function () {
  return gulp
    .src('app/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['compile']);
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

When I run `gulp compile` I got the following error:

```
...
app/hero.service.ts(7,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
app/hero.service.ts(11,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
...
```

But when I compile with the typescript compiler `tsc` compilation works perfectly.

In order to compile it with gulp I had to add the following reference path in `app/main.ts`:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Why do I have to do that with `gulp-typescript` but not with `tsc`?

Here the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist/app",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in how you supply source files and tsconfig.json to the gulp-typescript plugin. Try having your gulp task as following:

```
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('compile', function() 
{
    var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = tsProject.src().pipe(typescript(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));        
});
```

Hope this helps.